# Increment int column in several tables in one statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to make that when I increment the column of a row of a table, it increments in the column of a row of several other tables.

I had thought to make a trigger on this table and to make a procedure which increments all these values but I do not know if it is optimized. Do you think this solution is the right one or do you have another one? Using Postgresql

Comment: this sounds like bad design, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm making a polling system, and I'd like to be able to count how many votes a user has made, how many votes a choice has and how many total votes a poll has. In order not to have to use COUNT for performance reasons I wanted to make it so that when I INSERT in my users choices table, increment the number of votes of the user, the choice and the poll

Comment: how about just a view, would be much easier then trying to maintain count columns in different tables every time something changes.

Comment: Yes I had the idea to update all of them  with 3 statements. That’s right ?

Comment: I have no idea how your db is set up but I would think you do one insert into one table and all other information can be derived using a view. trying to use a bunch of triggers to keep your db in sync sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: again I don't know your table structure but are trying to keep a many to many relationship in sync with these triggers?  if so the actual solution is to make a junction table to keep track of the many to many relationship.

Comment: All I want is that if I insert a row in my "user_choices" table it increments in "user_choices_votecount" my vote_count column for the user, my vote_count column for the "poll_choice_votecount" table and my vote_count column for the "polls" table

Comment: So that I can know how many choices my user has made, how many users have made choice X, and how many votes my poll has.

Comment: Here's my db schema https://pastebin.com/NFa5geHk

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I've made a trigger that looks like this:

```sql
create or replace function increment_poll_vote_count()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql as
$$
begin
    INSERT INTO guilds_polls_user_choices_vote_count (guild_id, poll_id, user_id, vote_count)
    VALUES (new.guild_id, new.poll_id, new.user_id, 1)
    ON CONFLICT (guild_id, poll_id, user_id) DO UPDATE
        SET vote_count = guilds_polls_user_choices_vote_count.vote_count + 1;

    INSERT INTO guilds_polls_choices_vote_count (guild_id, poll_id, choice_id, vote_count)
    VALUES (new.guild_id, new.poll_id, new.choice_id, 1)
    ON CONFLICT (guild_id, poll_id, choice_id) DO UPDATE
        SET vote_count = guilds_polls_choices_vote_count.vote_count + 1;

    UPDATE guilds_polls
    SET vote_count = guilds_polls.vote_count + 1
    WHERE guild_id = new.guild_id
      AND poll_id = new.poll_id
      AND (SELECT vote_count
           FROM guilds_polls_user_choices_vote_count
           WHERE guild_id = new.guild_id
             AND poll_id = new.poll_id
             AND user_id = new.user_id) = 1;
    return new;
end
$$;
create or replace function decrement_poll_vote_count()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql as
$$
begin
    UPDATE guilds_polls_user_choices_vote_count
    SET vote_count = guilds_polls_user_choices_vote_count.vote_count - 1
    WHERE guild_id = old.guild_id
      AND poll_id = old.poll_id
      AND user_id = old.user_id
      AND vote_count > 0;

    UPDATE guilds_polls_choices_vote_count
    SET vote_count = guilds_polls_choices_vote_count.vote_count - 1
    WHERE guild_id = old.guild_id
      AND poll_id = old.poll_id
      AND choice_id = old.choice_id
      AND vote_count > 0;

    UPDATE guilds_polls
    SET vote_count = guilds_polls.vote_count - 1
    WHERE guild_id = old.guild_id
      AND poll_id = old.poll_id
      AND (SELECT vote_count
           FROM guilds_polls_user_choices_vote_count
           WHERE guild_id = old.guild_id
             AND poll_id = old.poll_id
             AND user_id = old.user_id) = 0;
    return new;
end
$$;
create trigger on_user_vote
    after insert
    on guilds_polls_user_choices
    for each row
execute procedure increment_poll_vote_count();
create trigger on_user_unvote
    after delete
    on guilds_polls_user_choices
    for each row
execute procedure decrement_poll_vote_count();
```